# unidic-lite install error: Locking...ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) exited with 1

Tags: locking, metadata, pipenv

I wanted to launch mecab-python3 and unidic-lite.

I could install mecab-python3 under pipenv python 3.9.17 but keep failing to install unidic-lite.

```
pipenv install unidic-lite
Installing unidic-lite...
Resolving unidic-lite...
Adding unidic-lite to Pipfile's [packages] ...
✔ Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (787ad5) out of date, updating to (c0e090)...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
⠹ Locking...ERROR:pip.subprocessor:[present-rich] Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) exited with 1
✘ Locking Failed!
```

this is error code and Pipfile below

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pandas = "*"
wheel = "*"
setuptools = "*"
pip = "*"
requests = "*"
mecab-python3 = "*"
cmake = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
python_full_version = "3.9.17"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```

I tried to find something from google couldn't find matching case...need help